# OpenMP, does taskwait imply flush

Tags: openmp

The question is short:  does `omp taskwait` imply `flush` or does it have to be explicit?

I looked thru description but could not find a definite answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [Specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf):

*"A flush region without a list is implied at the following locations: ...
   Immediately before and immediately after every task scheduling point."*(description flush)

in combination with:

*"The taskwait region includes an implicit task scheduling point in the current task region. The current task region is suspended at the task scheduling point until all child tasks that it generated before the taskwait region complete execution."* (description taskwait)

This makes your answer:

There is an **implicit** `flush` at `omp taskwait`